# CSS3 Slider Animation Issue

Tags: html, css

[Here is a link to my Portfolio.](http://niknakmakattack.com/index4.html)

In the bottom half, you'll see the portfolio div and short of the fact that it's not centered, I'm trying to do some CSS3 animations on it to mimic a slider. However, I am having a hell of a time trying to get it to work.

[Here is a link to the CodePen.](http://codepen.io/ishio/pen/ylDIi)

Short of the colors,the footer not working by sitting at the bottom at all times *dont' want to set a height*, I need help trying to figure out where I'm going wrong with my transitions from left to right in my slider.

I was following two different tutorials, and trying to dissect them to achieve what I have here. The main reason I am going through route as opposed to using JavaScript is that

- I haven't learned it yet
- I feel that CSS is going to transform into a very, very powerful tool.

My goal is to make my entire portfolio website JavaScript free.

If someone can take a look and offer suggestions, that'd be fantastic!!!

Comment: Try making a website without a single image, now that is a tricky one. (My best attempt: http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/Project/) Pertaining to your question, if you can not set the height of your footer then you most likely will need to result to javascript. I can show you where to go with that but I don't think css can achieve this by it's self without a set height.

Comment: There is a set height on the footer. I got the slider to work, now I just am having an issue centering it within the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7q9Jb/) that is working as a pure CSS slider that I kludged from [HERE](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/).
You can just plug the HTML into your middle div, and add the CSS, and make some adjustments.

Can you explain your problem with the footer a bit more?

The HTML is straight-forward, and here is the CSS:

```
img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
#slider {
   background: #000;
   border: 5px solid #eaeaea;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   height: 300px;
   width: 400px;
   margin: 40px auto 0;
   overflow: visible;
   position: relative;
}
#mask {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 320px; 
}
@keyframes cycle {
   0%  { top: 0px; } 
   4%  { top: 0px; }
   16% { top: 0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
   20% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; } 
   21% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
   92% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   96% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; } 
   100%{ top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes cycletwo {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   16% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   20% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   24% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   36% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
   40% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   41% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
   100%{ top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}
@keyframes cyclethree {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   36% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   40% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   44% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; } 
   56% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; } 
   60% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   61% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; } 
   100%{ top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}
@keyframes cyclefour {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   56% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   60% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   64% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   76% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
   80% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   81% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
   100%{ top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}
@keyframes cyclefive {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   76% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   80% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   84% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   96% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
   100%{ top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
}
@keyframes move {
   0% { transform: translateX(0); }
   100% { transform: translateX(100px); }
} 
@keyframes move {
   0% { transform: translateX(0); }
   50% { transform: translateX(20px); } 
   100% { transform: translateX(100px); }
}
#slider ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
}
#slider li { 
   width: 680px;
   height: 320px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -325px;
   list-style: none;
}
#slider li.firstanimation {
   animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;        
}
#slider li.secondanimation {
   animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite; 
}
#slider li.thirdanimation {
   animation: cyclethree 25s linear infinite;       
}
#slider li.fourthanimation {
   animation: cyclefour 25s linear infinite;        
}
#slider li.fifthanimation {
   animation: cyclefive 25s linear infinite;        
}
```

Comment: Yeah I worked through that one there, however the top was causing an issue as I'm not sure where it's basing the top of. Is it the top of the screen or the div? I've tried messing with it quite a bit.

With the footer, it doesn't always sit at the bottom of the screen. Is there a better way to force it there without to many issues?

Comment: Here is a fiddle that shows how to "stick" the footer to the bottom - there is no 'height' on the footer. http://jsfiddle.net/fs5PS/1/

Comment: In terms of the slider, just take all of the HTML and put it in your middle div. Then adjust the CSS sizes to fit the div.